# Access denied when running migration on Prisma

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, prisma

I am learning Prisma and I can't do migration in my localhost.

I am using `docker-compose` to create an image of mysql and I have successfully connected to the DB, please see my `docker-compose.yml` and `schema.prisma` below:

**Prisma's version**

`"prisma": "^4.6.1"`

**docker-compose.yml**

```
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    networks:
      - dev
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: prismatutorial
      MYSQL_USER: prismatutorial
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: prismatutorial
      MYSQL_DATABASE: prisma_tutorial

    command: mysqld --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    cap_add:
      - ALL
networks:
  dev:

volumes:
  db-data:
    driver: local
```

**schema.prisma**

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  name String
}
```

**.env**

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://prismatutorial:prismatutorial@localhost:3306/prisma_tutorial"
```

Every time I run the command of `npx prisma migrate dev --name firstMigration` and I have the error as shown in the below message:

> Error: P3014
>
> Prisma Migrate could not create the shadow database. Please make sure the database user has permission to create databases. Read more about the shadow database (and workarounds) at https://pris.ly/d/migrate-shadow
>
> Original error: Error code: P1010
>
> User prismatutorial was denied access on the database prisma_tutorial

However, when I try to run `npx prisma db push` , I can see the table is successfully created in my localhost's DB and it doesn't have permission error.

I don't think I have to create a shadow database at this point.

Am I missing out something?

Or, the `docker-compose.yml` I have written is wrong?

Your help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

In this case, `npx prisma db push` is successfully creating the tables because it does not require a shadow database. Please note that you should use `db push` command for quick prototyping.

As you are using MySQL Database, the database user `prismatutorial` should have `CREATE, ALTER, DROP, REFERENCES ON *.* privileges` as per this [reference](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-migrate/shadow-database#shadow-database-user-permissions). Once you grant these permissions you should be able to use migrate commands.